# Find property of control by string in C#

Tags: c#

I know that this was asked million times but I do not how to define my search,so please have patience.
I want to make method which is going to set some proprieties  on control dynamical refer to sting sent to method.

something like this

```
public void SetGridColumnProperty(ref DataGridView grid,string columnName, string propretyName, string propertyValue  )
        {
           grid.Columns[columnName].("I know this can't be done as this") = propertyValue;

        }
```

I apologize if my question is hard to understand,
Here what I want to do
I am making WinForms app whic is using lot od Data Grid Views for displaying and editing data.
As I have needs to often change looks of my girds, add columns edit order and other My idea was to hold some kind of metadata for each DataGird on form, And when I showing form to user I want before I load 
my form set properties of grid by join metadata and properties of specific grid.
I want to have config files separated of real code in XML or in DataBase so when I do edits on my application I do not have to recompile new code, Just change my xml and at next loding forom it looks as I like

Comment: Can you improve your question a bit? I don't understand what you want to do. And why do you pass `grid` in by ref?

Comment: Use reflection, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxz4wk15(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: please rephrase the question.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I did edit, and I think that now is more clear, sorry again,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, There is no need to use `ref` keyword, because `DataGridView` is a reference type. Second, here is the solution:

```
    public void SetGridColumnProperty(DataGridView grid, string columnName, string propertyName, object propertyValue)
    {
        DataGridViewColumn dgvColumn = grid.Columns[columnName];
        typeof(DataGridViewColumn).GetProperty(propertyName).SetValue(dgvColumn, propertyValue, null);
    }
```

Sample:

```
SetGridColumnProperty(dataGridView1, "ColumnName", "Width", 500);
```

**Update**: Check the `CanWrite` property of the `PropertyInfo` class before invoking the SetValue method.

Answer (score 5):

OK so you're talking about Reflection. You can look up a lot of resources which will refer to the [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.aspx) Namespace.

To get you started setting a property you'll proabably want to you use MethodInfo along the following lines:

```
MethodInfo invokedMethod = grid.GetType().GetProperty("propertyName").GetSetMethod();                    
invokedMethod.Invoke(targetObject, parameters);
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using reflection, look at [GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb.aspx) on the type you need this for. This will return an array of [PropertyInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb.aspx) objects for each property. Check if [`CanWrite`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.canwrite.aspx) returns true for the property you need and then use [`SetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb5dd1f1.aspx) to set your property value.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `PropertyInfo` to get the Property of an Control and assign its value

```
public void SetGridColumnProperty(ref DataGridView grid,string columnName, string propretyName, string propertyValue  )
        {
            PropertyInfo pInfo =  grid.GetType().GetProperty(propretyName);
            if (pInfo != null)
            {
               TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(pInfo.PropertyType);
               if (tc.CanConvertFrom(Type.GetType(propertyValue.GetType().ToString())))
               {
                   valToSet = tc.ConvertFromString(propertyValue);
                   pInfo.SetValue(grid, valToSet, null);
               }
            }
        }
```

hope this helps